# Dynamics 365 CRM specify base path for nextLink

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata

When you request data from Dynamics CRM for a particular entity the results are capped at 5000 records (which is configurable via header `Prefer=odata.maxpagesize=3`) the result includes a link to the next page:

```
"@odata.nextLink": "https://company.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?
                      $skiptoken=%3Ccookie%20pagenumber=%222%22%20pagingcookie=..."
```

Is there a way to change the base path of the url? I access Dynamics via an internal gateway so my basepath is different. I'd like the returned URL to match my correct path.

If not I would have to do some string manipulation, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: I've settled on just doing a string replace on the base path. There doesn't seem to be a way to  configure it.